# Is Physics a Good Argument for Classical Math

Tags: physics, foundations, philosophy, constructive-mathematics

(I posted this on philosophy stackexchange as well.  Let me know if it belongs there more than here.)

Is the success of classic mathematics in predicting the outcome of experiments in our physical world a valid argument for the consistency of classical mathematics? (that is math using LEM/DNE, completed infinity, etc.) We can use classical calculus/analysis or probability theory/measure theory to model the physical world. Then we can make a prediction of an experiment within that model and compare it to the physical outcome. And to my understanding, any inconsistency between the expected and actual outcomes have always been an insufficient model and never a result of the math itself being bad--for, with most experiments we can change the model to be more accurate.

Is it possible to recreate every mathematical model and prediction in constructive/intuitionistic math? If not, and there are some models that only hold in classical math, is the success of that model a good argument for classical mathematics? How strong is it? What are some counterpoints?

Comment: What are LEM, DNE and completed infinity?

Comment: @Servaes  Law of Excluded Middle, Double Negation Elimination.  Completed infinity is treating an infinite set as an object as apposed to treating infinity constructively

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Also, I do not see any relation between the fact that some mathematics predicts some physical events, and the question whether that piece of mathematics is consistent. Could you clarify the relation, or how this should give an argument for consistency?

Comment: No, Physics is not validation for the "consistency" of mathematics! *"As far as the laws of mathematics refer to reality, they are not certain, and as far as they are certain, they do not refer to reality"* -Albert Einstein.

Comment: Cross-posting questions are generally discouraged.

Comment: cool thanks for letting me know   ill take one of them down

Comment: In *Language, Truth and Logic*, A J Ayer argued for a negative answer to this question, on the grounds that we'd react to a surprising observation by changing our physical claims, not our mathematical ones: in particular, we'd never claim $2+2$ was empirically unequal to $4$, but rather that certain physical events don't honour the mathematical $+$. I wish I had a quotation to hand.